# Pop-up window positioning with Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, popup

My web application has a search field where user can enter some tags to search by. The window should pop-up just under the search field, like in the picture below:
[image: Popup window example]

The main detail I need to understand is how is the window positioning implemented. Is it some hidden div with absolute positioning and z-index?
I am interested in the most common Vanilla Javascript, HTML5, and CSS approaches.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @ezpresso Use JQuery. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Paulie_D, I understand. I will provide the details.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion box is an autocomplete component. You could very well use the jQuery Token Input by James Smith (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

As far as the position curiosity:

It's just a matter of alignment to the bottom of the input element. That can be done using pure CSS.

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
}

.spanClass {
  display: none;
}

.focusAlign input[type="text"]:focus~.spanClass {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 8px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 3px;
  font: .75em sans-serif;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="focusAlign">
  <input id="same" type="text" value="" />
  <span class="spanClass">
    <p>Oh, this is a suggestion.</p>
    <p>Yeah, well, so am I.</p>
    <p>Me, too!</p>
    <p>Whatever, I'm here.</p>
  </span>
</div>
```